# delaying asynchronous callbacks

Tags: c#

how to give delays for a asynchronous callbacks, is there any way to pause,or resume(current process for a certain time),or  any availability of sleep mode

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
Thread.Sleep()
```

There's also [System.Thread.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) for scheduling callbacks in the future, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: ita a single callbacks and it need to be paused and resumed

Comment: please i am in need of this answer

Comment: What do you mean by "pause and resume" a callback? Can you give an example?

Comment: i send a file in to 10 parts with a time gap to remote system using callbacks

Comment: In that case, I would say System.Thread.Timer is probably what you want. You can start/stop the timer at any time. Check the page I linked to for an example.